# Adding Arcs in Real Time to Datamaps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

In my code, I have several arcs being formed within the US map. However, I am confused as to how to draw arcs whose coordinates are added in realtime. I am simulating this by using a working sleep function for 10 seconds. The code is here: https://pastebin.com/D2gSydUS

Here is where I define and call the arcs:

```
var arcs = [
            {
                origin: {
                    latitude: 64.2008,
                    longitude: -149.4937
                },
                destination: {
                    latitude: 21.289373,
                    longitude: -157.917480
                }
            },
            {
                origin: {
                    latitude: 37.618889,
                    longitude: -122.375
                },
                destination: {
                    latitude: 30.194444,
                    longitude: -97.67
                }
            }
        ];

        map.arc(arcs, {strokeWidth: 2});
```

I've seen examples online but the datamaps website doesn't have any detail and the source code for it hasn't been particularly helpful either.

What the screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: Your code works, just need to call `map.arc` again:  see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEncJlAFLMWIfru6p9DW?p=preview)

Comment: @Mark Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to add pins to source + destination of the drawn arc? Thank you!